# Why was my question closed as "opinion-based" and deleted within 5 hours of closing?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, deleted-questions

My question, [What weaknesses of FunScript should I be aware of?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178978/what-weaknesses-of-funscript-should-i-be-aware-of), was put on hold as "as primarily opinion-based".
Some people left comments within a few hours; they are very useful for me.

My questions for Meta are:

1. Why should it be deleted? I don't think answers to that question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions. The comment that "FunScript doesn't support Typescript 0.9" is opinion based?
2. Is deleting within 5 hours proper? I have heard that on-hold questions will be kept for 48 hours.
3. Is there way for my question to appear again? Comments or answers for my question would be very useful to me.

[image]

Comment: Who's flagging this for reopening? It's off topic! Do people not read the text?

Answer (score 13):

FWIW, I think that question has problems. But that's not what this is about.

The question isn't offensive, asked in bad faith, or *egregiously bad* - so it didn't need to be deleted so quickly.

However, folks were getting *very rude* in the comments. If folks can't discuss the appropriateness of a question without calling names, that's a problem. The moderator handling the flags on this presumably decided that babysitting the discussion wasn't going to be productive, and after removing the flagged comment removed the question entirely.

The question is restored, for now; please keep the discussion civil and focus on the question itself and not the folks debating its appropriateness. If that's not possible, it will be removed again.

Comment: The question got put on hold before I made the comment that got deleted. Let's just be more careful about putting questions on hold so fast, shall we?

Comment: Generally-speaking, I would prefer to see questions closed - and re-opened, if need-be - quickly rather than slowly. The goal is to shut down a question until/unless problems are corrected - no sense in delaying there.

Comment: @KenSmith: What about that question is actually on-topic?  It's an opinion question, and a big list one at that.

Comment: @KenSmith The inappropriate comments got it *deleted*.  It's on hold because it's not at all an appropriate question for this site because it's both a primarily opinion based question, as well as a list question and and an overly broad question.  Those problems, normally, wouldn't result in such quick deletion, even though they more than justify closure.

Answer (score 7):

1. Questions are deleted when they don't add value to the site, and when it's not possible for the question to be improved into one that *would* add value.
2. Questions can be deleted right away by either having a moderator delete it (which was the case here) or the question having a score of -3 or less (not the case here) and having 3 users with 20k+ rep vote to delete it.  The question wouldn't be able to be deleted by non-moderator users for 48 hours given that it had a positive score.
3. A moderator would need to decide to undelete the question for it to be publicly visible, but you can see your own deleted questions, so *you* can see it even though it's deleted.  If you go to your profile and then go to the "questions" tab there is a link, "deleted recent questions" where you can find it.

---

As for your question being opinion based, here are some of the factors leading to that.  You say:

> I need some javascript alternative to create product level stock chart component. Candidates are Typescript,FunScript,WebSharper.

This gives the impression that you're asking for *opinions* on which of these you should use.

You also conclude by saying:

> If there is anyone who experienced some,please advice to me.

So you're asking for *advice*, i.e. *opinions*.

Next, you give a list of various "difficulties with FunScript" as being:

> 1. difficult to get informations.
> 2. difficult to debug compared to using raw javascript or Typescript.
> 3. lack of affinity for javascript.
> 4. insufficient maturation in some points.

These are all opinions.  These aren't verifiable facts, further leading to the impression that you're looking for opinions about what people do/don't like about something, rather than concrete facts.

Next, if we were to assume that you weren't asking for opinions, and that you really were looking solely for a list of verifiable facts about FunScript, the question would then just become "Too broad" as it's a list of things that can be quite large, what should be included in the list is also subjective (is that fact about the product an advantage, a disadvantage, or neither, that's opinion), would need to be maintained over time, etc.  These types of list questions aren't the types of questions that we want here.

Comment: I feel I don't understand why opinion based answer isn't proper in the first place.

Comment: @MasahikoMiyasaka In general, they aren't, this site has simply chosen to exclude them from it's scope.  They can be hard to deal with, don't really fit into the  q/a model that the site uses, requires dramatically more moderation (because they so often get out of hand, just like your question did), and in general have a very low signal to noise ratio.

Comment: Ok,I understand opinion isn't proper for this site.

But you wrote these below are all opinions.

>1. difficult to get informations.
1. difficult to debug compared to using raw javascript or Typescript.
1. lack of affinity for javascript.
1. insufficient maturation in some points.
 
What is the fact?The fact is something can be displayed with some obvious numbers?

For example,the number of result from goole for "javascript" is over 798 million,and that one for "Funscript" is 7710.
It isn't fact?This means "difficult to get informations."?

Comment: @MasahikoMiyasaka Giving numbers in quantities of search results is a fact, saying that it is hard to find information is an opinion.  How easy it is to find information about a subject is not strictly a matter of how many results there are in google.  If there's only one result in the whole internet, but it's a great resource with all the information you'd ever need, then information isn't hard to find.  How easy information is to find will also be dependent on the person.  Some people's intuitive ideas of what to search for may be better, for example.

Comment: "There is less informations about FunScript." is fact or opinion?

Still,I don't understand differencies between opinion and fact.
Argument about preference of static or dynamic has lots of opinion like below.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583507/moving-from-static-language-to-dynamic

I feel argument excluding any opinion isn't possible.

Comment: @MasahikoMiyasaka "There is less information" is something that you'd need to back up.  It's not an opinion, but it's also something that you'd need to prove if you wanted to make that assertion.

Comment: It's damned silly in my opinion to be so aggressive about excluding questions that have an element of opinion in them. This is coding, folks! I want to hear people's opinions, even if I don't agree with them. Some of the very best questions and answers *ever* on this site have had a huge element of opinion to them. THAT SHOULD BE OK.

Comment: @KenSmith There are *thousands* of sites in which you are allowed and encouraged to share your opinions in which there is no requirement of (or expecation of) quality content.  This isn't one of those sites.  In fact, it's one of very few places people can go to to get *away* from that.  Basically every other similar site allows such questions.  Look where it got them.

Comment: @KenSmith: There are dozens (if not hundreds) of other sites you can go to find opinion-based answers to things. SO isn't a site for "Let's discuss this topic". It's designed as a repository of *knowledge*, not *debate, opinion, discussion, and argument*. Sorry, but if the guidelines here aren't suitable, you can post a request here on Meta to have them changed (and see how fast you collect downvotes from those opposing them). Otherwise, the solution may be to just choose not to use SO and take your business elsewhere. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite - Thanks, I'll give that a shot. I've been getting frustrated lately by seeing lots of questions that I think are perfectly interesting and helpful getting shut down. I'd rather not take my business elsewhere, because (even with that), SO remains the best all-around site for programmers anywhere. I'd much rather talk people into relaxing the restrictions than go elsewhere.

Comment: @KenSmith Many people have asked for the same thing.  The discussions have happened time and time again.  The result of those discussions has been that these types of questions aren't welcome.  You have not brought anything new to the table.

Answer (score -6):

I've been getting very grumpy at our StackOverlords lately for deleting, closing or otherwise putting on hold perfectly valid, helpful, interesting questions. That's why I was grumpy when I made my comment about the "nazis" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Soup_Nazi) who keep closing questions that I would really like to see remain open. (Apparently that was one of the comments that got deleted, but the question was closed long before I made that comment.)

Don't get me wrong, there are lots and lots of questions that do deserve to be closed. But people are getting too aggressive is doing so, and this question is a perfect example of that. I don't know how to fix this, but I want to register my opinion - it's been registered plenty in various other places, but I want to register it again - that folks need to stop closing questions that are perfectly valid, interesting, helpful, and contribute to the overall health and interest of the community.

Comment: Yes, everyone has an opinion and they want to share it.  That's the problem.  It fills the topics with noise in which there is very little useful or helpful information.  They become bikeshed questions that detract from the more valuable content.

Comment: There's an old expression: Opinions are like rectums; everyone has one, and they all stink. :-) There are plenty of other sites where you can have opinion based discussions/arguments/debates. SE is designed as a knowledge repository, and speculation on what someone "might need to be aware of" isn't knowledge (that's why it's called *speculation*). If you want to see how the community feels about changing the guidelines to allow discussion and opinion posts, just post a request here at Meta asking to have them changed, and note how many negative votes you receive (and how quickly).

Comment: I don't understand differences between fact and opinion still.
In question below,I asked pros and cons of WebSharper to toyvo,it's improper?JonHarrop wrote some of his experiences,it's improper?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178978/what-weaknesses-of-funscript-should-i-be-aware-of?noredirect=1#comment28374636_19178978

Comment: I got lots of information from talking of that thread.They are very useful for me.

Comment: "It's cloudy": fact. "Bad weather": opinion.

Comment: @MasahikoMiyasaka: Read the close reason. Yes, it’s improper. The very fact that somebody replied with “experiences” is a pretty good sign that your question is open to opinion and not specific enough.

Comment: @brasofilo:"Actor model will reduce bugs compared to shared state model." is fact or opinion?

Comment: @minitech:How about asking pros and cons of WebSharper to toyvo?

Comment: @MasahikoMiyasaka To your first, that's an opinion unless you're able to back it up, i.e. concrete observed evidence of actual bug counts given the two methods.  As for the second, that's "too broad".  It's a list question.  They are not appropriate here either.

Comment: @Servy:If you mean we should answer depending on obvious fact,I understand.If you mean we can't write any answer without obvious fact,I think most of answer have to be deleted.

Comment: @Servy: You said that that's "too broad".What does "that" point? My question to minitech? or My original question?

Comment: Just to toss out my opinion again (though nobody seems to agree), I found the original question quite helpful, I found the answers helpful, and I learned from having the question up there. That happens to be my criteria for a helpful site. I'm not entirely sure why folks seem to want SO to be anything but that.

Comment: @MasahikoMiyasaka Both your original question, and your previous comment asking for a list of pros and cons.  It's not specific enough for an SO question.

Comment: @Servy: OK I understand about "too broad".I think still that sometime broad question is useful like my question.

BTAIM,how about the balance between opinion and fact?

Comment: @MasahikoMiyasaka While they can potentially be useful, they also have a *lot* of problems associated with them, and as such they aren't allowed on this site.  Once again, there are many other sites that don't prohibit them; you're more than welcome to ask such questions elsewhere.